# how to avoid browser not responding due to infinite loop of http request

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get data from a sensor in milliseconds and then calculate the average value within ten seconds to alert based on the average value. The problem is that this code runs well as long as the while loop been set to less than 1000 or one second and when I set it to larger numbers(I want the loop to work infinitely and stop with a button function). I want to know if there any way to function this infinite loop in Javascript?
Here is my code:

```
const now = Date.now();
var epochTime = now;
//Arrey of the  value
var Arrey = [];
Counter =0

while (epochTime<now+10000000) { //should be set infinite and stop with button
    $.get('http://xxx/'+epochTime, function(data){
    let myValue= data.data[354708094967841].crosscorrelations[0].value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +="<br/>"+ myValue ;      
    Arrey.push(myValue);
    console.log(Arrey);
    var sum =0;
    console.log(epochTime);
    if (Counter>=10000 && Counter%10000==0){ 
        for ( i=Counter-10000; i<Counter; i++)   
        sum = sum + Arrey[i];
        valueAverage= sum/10000;
        console.log(valueAverage);  
        document.getElementById("valueAverage").innerHTML +="<br/>"+ valueAverage;  
        if (valueAverage>0.01){ 

            alert("the value ave is high");  // ----> to check the code



        }else{

            alert("the value ave is low"); //-----> to check the code
        } 



    }


    console.log(Counter);
    Counter++;
    console.log(myValue);    //get data from value in async version
     });

     epochTime ++;
}
```

Comment: since `$.get` is asynchronous your loop will start thousands of requests - none of which will be processed until that loop finishes

Comment: so  should  I use the http request with sync attribute?

Comment: no - since *synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the main thread is deprecated* in any browser worth using - you need to rethink what you're doing (promise chaining may be what you want to do - and $.get does return a (sort of) promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments said: `$.get()` is asynchronous, so it doesn't wait. What you could do, is wrap the get request in a function and call the function from within the request, thus creating a loop. So sort of like this:

```
var buttonClicked = false;

//Function simply wraps the get request so that it can be called at anytime
function getSensorData(){
    $.get('http://xxx/'+epochTime, function(data){
        let myValue = data.data[354708094967841].crosscorrelations[0].value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br/>" + myValue;
        Arrey.push(myValue);
        console.log(Arrey);
        var sum = 0;
        console.log(epochTime);
        if (Counter >= 10000 && Counter % 10000 == 0) {
            for (i = Counter - 10000; i < Counter; i++)
                sum = sum + Arrey[i];
            valueAverage = sum / 10000;
            console.log(valueAverage);
            document.getElementById("valueAverage").innerHTML += "<br/>" + valueAverage;
            if (valueAverage > 0.01) {
                alert("the value ave is high"); // ----> to check the code

            } else {
                alert("the value ave is low"); //-----> to check the code
            }
        }
        console.log(Counter);
        Counter++;
        console.log(myValue); //get data from value in async version

        //Now that you're done with everything, you can check if the button is clicked and if it is, don't run the function again.

       if (!buttonClicked){
          getSensorData();
       }
    }
}

//Here we check if the button is clicked and change the variable when it is
$("#stopButton").click(function(){
   buttonClicked = true;
});
```

Also, quick note: Variables in javascript are usually camelCase, not Capitalized; constants are the exception because they are generally ALLCAPS.

Comment: Thank you very much I will test this code. Also, thank you very much for your note